# Django-Pass data from html to python and wise versa

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-urls

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="grid" method="POST" action="{% url 'result' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <textarea name="name" /></textarea>
   <button type="submit"">Detect</button>
</form>
<label>{{ result }}</label>
<body>
</html>
```

**view.py**

```
def test_data_preprocessing(test_data1):
    test_data1 = test_data1.lower()
    test_data1 = re.compile(
        r"(http|https|ftp|ssh)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"
    ).sub("", test_data1)
    test_data1 = re.compile(r"<.*?>").sub("", test_data1)  # remove tags
    test_data1 = TextBlob(test_data1).correct()  # Speeling correction
    test_data1 = "".join(
        filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), test_data1)
    )  # remove numbers
    test_data1 = contractions.fix(test_data1)  # contraction
    test_data1 = remove_stop(test_data1)  # stop word removal
    test_data1 = re.compile(r"[^\w\s]").sub(
        "", test_data1
    )  # '[^\w\s]',''   this convert all puntuations, underscores, alphabets to null(not of word characters and space)
    test_data1 = word_tokenize(test_data1)  # Tokenization
    test_data1 = [
        lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, get_wordnet_pos(w)) for w in test_data1
    ]  # Lemmatization
    return test_data1
def result(request):
    namee = request.POST['name']
    namee =  test_data_preprocessing(namee)
    return render(
    request,
        "index.html",
        {"name":namee}
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from mywebsite import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homePage, name='result'),
    path("", views.result),
]
```

I'm making a website using Django where I have to get data from html page in python file and after getting data I have to perform some preprocessing on data. and after that again return back to the same page with some new information when i press a button. The problem is that when I press button than I move to the same page, but the new information is not displaying after clicking on a button. Is there any way to move information in the same page?

Comment: check how to use ajax

Comment: but i want to pass data to python

Comment: Use REST APIs to send data from js to  server. Use post request to send data, and use get to fetch data form APIs

Comment: re-render the same html page with new information(might  be a solution)

Comment: any way using jquery, and django-rest is won't take much time to learn and implement

Comment: not working rerender solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `action` attribute of HTML if you see it correctly, there should be `""` in action, currently they are missing so it should be:

```html
action="{% url 'result' %}"
```

Not:

```html
action={% url 'result' %}
```

> **Note:** You can also simply remove the `action` attribute as Django by default takes current page route.

Secondly, your view name is `result` in views.py and you define it as `homePage` in urls.py, kindly see it.

Also the view should pass some `context` dict so:

```py
def result(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    actual_name=preprocessing(name)
    return render(
    request,
        "index.html",
        {"name":actual_name}
    )
```

#### Edit:

Try this urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from mywebsite import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homePage, name='home-page'),
    path("result/", views.result, name="result"),
]
```

Try this `result` view:

```py
def result(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        namee = request.POST['name']
        namee2 =  test_data_preprocessing(namee)
        return render(
            request,
            "index.html",
           {"name":namee2}
        )
     return render(
            request,
            "index.html"
     )
```

Try this template:

```html
<form class="grid" method="POST" action="{% url 'result' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <textarea name="name" /></textarea>
   <button type="submit"">Detect</button>
</form>

{% if name %}
    <label>{{ name }}</label>
{% else %}
    <p> name is not coming as it is GET request.</p>
```

Comment: when i used the above solution that is provided than an exception value get "Reverse for 'result' not found. 'result' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: @coderunning check the spelling of reverse, also change your view name to `result` in urls.py as same in view.

Comment: @coderunning just remove the action attribute. There are also triple quotes in `type="submit""` it should be only `type="submit"`.

Comment: i added path("", views.result), this path in urls.py and also change the name to result but again same exception value get

Comment: @coderunning Can you show the full traceback by editing the question and your current code?

Comment: @coderunning Did you define any `app_name` in urls.py above?

Comment: yes i used app name as "mywebsite"

Comment: @coderunning change the name of `homePage` as `name="home-page"` and provide the `name="result"` in `result` view, it will work.

Comment: def home-Page(request):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   this is displaying syntex error

Comment: @coderunning I mean to change the `name` in urls.py not view name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251712/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-code-running).

Comment: i changed 
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homePage, name='home-page'),
 path("", views.result, name='result'),
]  but it is also not displaying new information

Comment: @coderunning It is because you have both the variable names as `namee` in `reusult` view, you should change one of them, see in my answer above.